# Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have schedular annotation on abstract class so that child classes doesnt need to have the annotations. Something similar to this in the abstract class

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractTestClass {

    @Bean
    public String getDelay() {
        return "1000";
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{@getDelay}")
    public void callScheduledMethod() {
        getZeroBytesFile();
    }

    public abstract void getZeroBytesFile();
}

@Component
public class ChildClass extends AbstractTestClass {

    @Override
    public String getDelay() {
        return "5000";
    }

    @Override
    public void getZeroBytesFile() {
        System.out.println("called");
    }

}

@Component
public class OtherClass {

    // This bean initialisation throws error
    @AutoWired ChildClass childClass;

}
```

But it doesnt work and throws this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDelay': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Spring is probably trying to proxy the class (you didn't show the entire stack trace) in order to apply the scheduling advice. That said, you seem to be mixing `@Bean` (which applies only to configurations) and `@Scheduled` (which should be used only on services. Also, don't use `get` in bean-method names, and don't create beans of such broad types as `String`.

Comment: You are referencing a bean that is being created by the same component. Hence it isn't going to work, because the component needs to exist before the bean can be created. Hence a circular dependency on the `@Component` itself. I would suggest to simply stick with the `@Scheduled` as you are now making things more complex. It also won't work with multiple instances, as there will be multiple `getDelay` beans created.

Answer (score 2):

this is the trick to achieve this:

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractTestClass {

    @Bean
    public String getDelay() {
        return "1000";
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{@getDelay}")
    public void callScheduledMethod() {
        getZeroBytesFile();
    }

    public abstract void getZeroBytesFile();
}

@Component
public class ChildClass extends AbstractTestClass {

    @Override
    public String getDelay() {
        return "5000";
    }

    @Override
    public void getZeroBytesFile() {
        System.out.println("called");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works well without any manual object creation of the extended classes. But when i create an instance of object with `@AutoWired` annotation it fails with same error. `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1058E: A problem occurred when trying to resolve bean 'getSchedulerDelay':'Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory`. Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: @Shettyh please update your question and add the code that makes problem, I will check it ;)

Comment: Updated the question please check

Comment: just worked fine without any exception using `2.2.2.RELEASE`